# MediaPlayer Framework iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to implement video into my app and I am having a hard time. I have tried [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mediaplayer-framework_mpmovieplayercontroller_ios4/) tutorial and it was super helpful.

But now when I try to run my app and click on the button, the video frame comes up and just stays black. My video is in the correct format, I also made sure that I am pulling in the MediaPlayer Framework. Has anyone ran into this issue before or knows why this would be happening?

This is what I have:

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *playButton = (UIButton *) sender; 

    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"big-buck-bunny-clip" ofType:@"m4v"];

    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(38, 100, 250, 163)];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    //moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

    moviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime = 5;

    [moviePlayerController play];

}
```

Comment: Your moviePlayerController has a weak reference because it is defined inside the playMovie method and released before the movie begins playing. You need to have a strong property for the moviePlayerController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view onto your view?

```
MPMoviePlayerController *movieController = ...;
movieController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:movieController.view];
```

Frame could also be black if you've set `shouldAutoplay` to YES and controlStyle to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`

--Edit
This is how I init my player and it works, maybe that will be of some help. It's playing HTTP Live Streaming video, but it'll play anything you put into it. You should try the url in this sample. If it'll work then there's definitely some problem with your contentUrl.

```
  url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
  self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
  moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
  [self.view insertSubview:moviePlayerController.view atIndex:0];
  moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
  moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
  [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: MoviePlayerController takes some time for initialization with your URL, so you might also want to listen to MPMovieMediaTypesAvailableNotification. If you simply need to play the video remove [moviePlayerController play]; message and replace it with moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;

Comment: that does not seem to do the trick. I also created a new project just incase I was doing something wrong, even the new project does not work. Do you know of any other good tutorials for MediaPlayer Framework for iOS 5?

Comment: No, alas, I don't know any tutorials. Have you also tried to put your fileURL and filePath variables into NSLog? Maybe they're not properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and also following the same tutorial, but then I found the class moviePlayerViewController that its easier to use and you don't even have to worry about dismiss buttons.

I fixed used the following code: (I think it works better with ios5)

```
self.moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:finalurl];
moviePlayerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.fullscreen=YES;
```